# Macro by using #ifdef doesn't work

Tags: c++, c

I am using MACRO to define a variable SUCESS

```
#ifdef SUCCESS
    #undef SUCCESS
    #define SUCCESS  0
#endif //SUCCESS
```

But Eclipse compiler gives me error as

```
symbol "SUCCESS" could not be resolved
```

But if I write just

```
#define SUCCESS  0
```

It works fine. Why is it so. I have to write using #ifdef only

Comment: have you tried with another IDE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SUCCESS` is not defined before those preprocessing directives, there won't be any `SUCCESS` macro defined (that's the error). If you define `SUCCESS` before, its value will change as expected:

```
#define SUCCESS 1

#ifdef SUCCESS
    #undef SUCCESS
    #define SUCCESS  0
#endif //SUCCESS

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << SUCCESS;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aedb5db029bfb8fa).

Answer (score 6):

Rewrite it like this:

```
#undef SUCCESS
#define SUCCESS 0
```

That way, you get the definition regardless of whether `SUCCESS` has been previously defined. I also removed the `#ifdef ... #endif` wrapper. It's not needed: `#undef` is ignored if its target has not been defined.